# How to reset to a certain point in my code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class playerinput {

    private static final String  = null;
    private static Scanner user_input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String firstName;
        System.out.print("Enter your name here:");
        firstName = user_input.next();
        String lastName;
        System.out.print("Ok cool, and your last?:");
        lastName = user_input.next();
        String thankYou;
        thankYou = "Alright," + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ',' + ' '
         + "that's all we'll need. Have a nice day, and thank you again.";      
        System.out.println(thankYou);   
        System.out.println("Oh, one more question,");
        System.out.println("if you don't mind.");
        String Response = user_input.next();
        if (Response.equals("Yea?")||(Response.equals("Yes?")
                ||(Response.equals("Sure")))){
            System.out.println("How old are you, sir?");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That's not the answer");
            System.out.println("im looking for...");
            System.out.println("Please, reconsider.");
            String Response2 = user_input.next();
            if (Response2.equals("Fine")||(Response2.equals("Yea")||(Response2.equals("Yes")
                    ||(Response2.equals("Sure")||(Response2.equals("I guess")
                    ||(Response2.equals("I suppose"))))))){{
                System.out.println("Good, let us procede.");
                System.out.println("How old are you?");
                String Response3 = user_input.next();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Fine then, be that way.");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I simply want another else statement there, the last one
is apparently a syntax error and should be deleted.
How is this a syntax error? Am I missing something?
Please, I'm new and unskilled.

Comment: Indent your code properly for a start.

Comment: You have two brackets for the one `if` statement `))))))){{` kind of looks like that...

Comment: Double check your curly braces. Also, why use so many parentheses in your if statement when you are only using the conditional OR operator?

Comment: Eclipse made me do it Q_Q so less parentheses and try to follow along properly with the curly brackets and stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Java ( a || ( b || c )) can be written ( a || b || c ) which avoids the bracketitis your code is suffering from

but if i was to guess... its this line.

```
     if (Response2.equals("Fine")||(Response2.equals("Yea")(Response2.equals("Yes")
                ||(Response2.equals("Sure")||(Response2.equals("I guess")
                ||(Response2.equals("I suppose"))))))){{
```

looks like that extra curly brace on the end is unnecessary.